# SVG and TweenLite - Select class within parent

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap

I have a script modified from a tutorial that animates SVG strokes when the containing DIV comes into view (using inview.js). I have added a TweenLite animation that changes svg fill-opacity from 0 to 1. The problem is my addition does not care whether the containing DIV is in view (I'm using getElementsByClassName to target the SVG elements).

How can I target the elements by class name only if the containing DIV is in view? I guess I need to use "parentElement" in my TweenLite lines but I'm not sure how.

I have modified a function within svglines.js (everything after drawSVGPaths):

```
function replaceRectsWithPaths(parentElement) {
var rects = $(parentElement).find('rect');
$.each(rects, function() {
    var rectX = $(this).attr('x');
    var rectY = $(this).attr('y');
    var rectX2 = parseFloat(rectX) + parseFloat($(this).attr('width'));
    var rectY2 = parseFloat(rectY) + parseFloat($(this).attr('height'));
    var convertedPath = 'M' + rectX + ',' + rectY + ' ' + rectX2 + ',' + rectY + ' ' + rectX2 + ',' + rectY2 + ' ' + rectX + ',' + rectY2 + ' ' + rectX + ',' + rectY;
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', convertedPath)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(rects).remove();
}
function replaceLinesWithPaths(parentElement) {
var lines = $(parentElement).find('line');
$.each(lines, function() {
    var lineX1 = $(this).attr('x1');
    var lineY1 = $(this).attr('y1');
    var lineX2 = $(this).attr('x2');
    var lineY2 = $(this).attr('y2');
    var convertedPath = 'M' + lineX1 + ',' + lineY1 + ' ' + lineX2 + ',' + lineY2;
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', convertedPath)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(lines).remove();
}
function replaceCirclesWithPaths(parentElement) {
var circles = $(parentElement).find('circle');
$.each(circles, function() {
    var cX = $(this).attr('cx');
    var cY = $(this).attr('cy');
    var r = $(this).attr('r');
    var r2 = parseFloat(r * 2);
    var convertedPath = 'M' + cX + ', ' + cY + ' m' + (-r) + ', 0 ' + 'a ' + r + ', ' + r + ' 0 1,0 ' + r2 + ',0 ' + 'a ' + r + ', ' + r + ' 0 1,0 ' + (-r2) + ',0 ';
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', convertedPath)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(circles).remove();
}
function replaceEllipsesWithPaths(parentElement) {
var ellipses = $(parentElement).find('ellipse');
$.each(ellipses, function() {
    var cX = $(this).attr('cx');
    var cY = $(this).attr('cy');
    var rX = $(this).attr('rx');
    var rY = $(this).attr('ry');
    var convertedPath = 'M' + cX + ', ' + cY + ' m' + (-rX) + ', 0 ' + 'a ' + rX + ', ' + rY + ' 0 1,0 ' + rX*2 + ',0 ' + 'a ' + rX + ', ' + rY + ' 0 1,0 ' + (-rX*2) + ',0 ';
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', convertedPath)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(ellipses).remove();
}
function replacePolygonsWithPaths(parentElement) {
var polygons = $(parentElement).find('polygon');
$.each(polygons, function() {
    var points = $(this).attr('points');
    var polyPoints = points.split(/[ ,]+/);
    var endPoint = polyPoints[0] + ', ' + polyPoints[1];
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', 'M' + points + ' ' + endPoint)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(polygons).remove();
}
function replacePolylinesWithPaths(parentElement) {
var polylines = $(parentElement).find('polyline');
$.each(polylines, function() {
    var points = $(this).attr('points');
    $(SVG('path'))
    .attr('d', 'M' + points)
    .attr('fill', $(this).attr('fill'))
    .attr('stroke', $(this).attr('stroke'))
    .attr('stroke-width', $(this).attr('stroke-width'))
    .insertAfter(this);
});
$(polylines).remove();
}
function hideSVGPaths(parentElement) {
var paths = $(parentElement).find('path');
//for each PATH..
$.each( paths, function() {
    //get the total length
    var totalLength = this.getTotalLength();
    //set PATHs to invisible
    $(this).css({
        'stroke-dashoffset': totalLength,
        'stroke-dasharray': totalLength + ' ' + totalLength
    });
});
}
function drawSVGPaths(_parentElement, _timeMin, _timeMax, _timeDelay) {
var paths = $(_parentElement).find('path');
//for each PATH..
$.each( paths, function(i) {
    //get the total length
    var totalLength = this.getTotalLength();
    //set PATHs to invisible
    $(this).css({
        'stroke-dashoffset': totalLength,
        'stroke-dasharray': totalLength + ' ' + totalLength
    });
    //animate
    $(this).delay(_timeDelay*i).animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': 0
    }, {
        duration: Math.floor(Math.random() * _timeMax) + _timeMin
        ,easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    });
});
}
function replaceWithPaths(parentElement) {
replaceRectsWithPaths(parentElement);
replaceLinesWithPaths(parentElement);
replaceEllipsesWithPaths(parentElement);
replaceCirclesWithPaths(parentElement);
replacePolygonsWithPaths(parentElement);
replacePolylinesWithPaths(parentElement);    
}
function startSVGAnimation(parentElement) {
drawSVGPaths(parentElement, 500, 500, 300);
var svgWork = document.getElementsByClassName('svgWork');
TweenLite.to(svgWork, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(1);
var svgServices = document.getElementsByClassName('svgServices');
TweenLite.to(svgServices, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(2.5);
var svgCalc = document.getElementsByClassName('svgCalc');
TweenLite.to(svgCalc, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(3);
var svgTeam = document.getElementsByClassName('svgTeam');
TweenLite.to(svgTeam, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(1.5);
var svgWorkforus = document.getElementsByClassName('svgWorkforus');
TweenLite.to(svgWorkforus, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(2);

}
$(function() {
//if (!Modernizr.touch) {
    var animated = $('.js-animate');
    replaceWithPaths(animated);
    hideSVGPaths(animated);
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        $(animated).each(function(i) {
            if( $(this).visible() ) {
                startSVGAnimation(this);
                animated.splice(i,1);
            };
        });
    });
    $(document).scroll();
//};
});
```

Comment: Apologies but I am not understanding it correctly, what is the behaviour you are expecting to happen? And what really is happening? To me, it looks fine and the animation executes when it should i.e. when SVGs are in-view. Help me understand the problem please.

Comment: If one of the animations comes into view (one animation has 3 circles with icons+text, the other has 2 circles with icons+text), icons+text from all animations display. So I load the page and see "Services, Our Work, Instant Quote". Then I scroll down the page and the icons for "Meet the Team, Work For Us" are already visible, when they should still be hidden until the containing DIV comes into view fully.

Comment: And how does this `startSVGAnimation` method is called? What triggers it?

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the complete script. Hope this is not bad etiquette!

Comment: I think I know what the problem is but its a little too late here and am too tired to do something. Hopefully, we'll figure this out together tomorrow and hopefully you can wait too.

Comment: Thank you Tahir, I can wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a very quick-fix could be replacing all instances of `document` with `parentElement` inside your `startSVGAnimation` function.

So your `startSVGAnimation` would look like:

```
function startSVGAnimation(parentElement){
    drawSVGPaths(parentElement, 500, 500, 300);
    var svgWork = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('svgWork');
    TweenLite.to(svgWork, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(1);
    var svgServices = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('svgServices');
    TweenLite.to(svgServices, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(2.5);
    var svgCalc = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('svgCalc');
    TweenLite.to(svgCalc, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(3);
    var svgTeam = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('svgTeam');
    TweenLite.to(svgTeam, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(1.5);
    var svgWorkforus = parentElement.getElementsByClassName('svgWorkforus');
    TweenLite.to(svgWorkforus, 1, {attr:{"fill-opacity":1}}).delay(2);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly the solution I was trying to figure out. Thank you!